# Help with Skul bug

Tags: skul-the-hero-slayer

So I’ve just started playing Skul: The Hero Slayer on Steam and an annoying bug happened. All numbers disappeared: gold, crystals, hp. I can still see the hp bar and gold/crystal icons but no numbers. I tried reinstalling the game but nothing changed.